# Show detail window from Kendo UI Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI MVC

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Admin.Models.SiteActivityDaily>()
        .Name("chart")
        .Legend(l => l
           .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
        )
        .Tooltip(true)
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetSiteActivity", "Site")))
        .CategoryAxis(a => a
            .Categories(model => model.SiteDescription)
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Bar(d => d.ActivityCount).Name("Today");
        })

    )
```

Is it somehow possible to show a Kendo Window with details when clicking on each bar, passing the variable "SiteID" to a partial view loaded with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use plotAreaClick event to capture clicked value. See [Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-plotAreaClick)

```
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
      function chart_plotAreaClick(e) {
        console.log(e.value);
        //Here u open kendo window with value parameter
      }

      var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
      chart.bind("plotAreaClick", chart_plotAreaClick);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use kendo detailtemplate but you want to show the details in window.

So, wrap the detail template in kendo window.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [SeriesClick event](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/chart-api/events), then pass the value to the Kendo Window. The action executed by the Kendo Window will return the partial view which needs to be displayed.

```
<script>
    function handleSeriesClick(e) {
        var wnd = $("#MyWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        wnd.refresh({
            url: "someUrl",
            data: { serieValue: e.value) }
        });
        wnd.bind("refresh", function () {
            wnd.center();
            wnd.open();
        });
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Admin.Models.SiteActivityDaily>()
    .Name("chart")
    .Legend(l => l
       .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
    )
    .Tooltip(true)
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetSiteActivity", "Site")))
    .CategoryAxis(a => a
        .Categories(model => model.SiteDescription)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Bar(d => d.ActivityCount).Name("Today");
    })
    .Events(e => e.SeriesClick("handleSeriesClick"))
)

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("MyWindow")
    .Visible(false)
)
```